# Powershell - query all AD user objects; return email item count or no mailbox

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

below code when inputting a few users, but fails is not returning expected results when querying for all users in AD. Not understanding why it's failing on bulk users versus a relatively small user list

Code below:

```
$Users = @('user1',"user2",'user3','user4')
$Mailboxes = $Users | Get-ADuser -pr *


$OU = 'DC=local,DC=local,DC=org'
$Mailboxes = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -notlike '*$*'} -pr samaccountname
$Mailboxes = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OU -Properties samaccountname


foreach ($Mbx in $Mailboxes)
{
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser $Mbx.SamAccountName -Properties * #Enabled,AccountExpirationDate

    $UserObj = New-Object PSObject
    $UserObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Username" -Value $ADUser.SamAccountName

    If($mbx.msExchRecipientTypeDetails -eq $null)
        {     
        $UserObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "E-Mail" -Value "NoEmailAddress"
        $UserObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "email ItemCount" -Value "NoMailBox"
        $UserObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "TotalItemSize(GB)" -Value "NoMailBox"
        Write-Host $Mbx.SamAccountName "has no mailbox" -ForegroundColor green
        }
    Else
      {
        If($mbx.msExchRecipientTypeDetails -eq 1)
          {
            $stats = $Mbx.EmailAddress | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select-Object TotalItemSize,TotalDeletedItemSize,ItemCount,LastLogonTime,LastLoggedOnUserAccount
            $MbxSizeb = $stats.TotalItemSize -replace "(.*\()|,| [a-z]*\)"
            $Tmp_gb = $MbxSizeb/1GB
            $MbxSizeGB = [math]::Round($Tmp_gb,2)

            $UserObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "E-Mail" -Value $ADUser.EmailAddress
            $UserObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "email ItemCount" -Value $stats.ItemCount
            $UserObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "TotalItemSize(GB)" -Value $MbxSizeGB
          }
      }  
    $Report = $Report += $UserObj
}
```

Results with selected users
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCQ3L.png)

Results against all users:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2biB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the property `msExchRecipientTypeDetails` when populating the `$Mailboxes` variable. Lines 5 and 6 should read `-Properties msExchRecipientTypeDetails`

---

Update: So this wasn't completely correct. You can use your code if you change `If($mbx.msExchRecipientTypeDetails -eq $null)` to `If($aduser.msExchRecipientTypeDetails -eq $null)`. However, you really don't need to get the ADUser again. $Mailboxes is a collection of ADUsers. Changes lines 2,6,7 to `-Properties EmailAddress,msExchRecipientTypeDetails,SamAccountName`

```
$Users = @('user1',"user2",'user3','user4')
$Mailboxes = $Users | Get-ADuser -Properties EmailAddress,msExchRecipientTypeDetails,SamAccountName

#$OU = 'DC=local,DC=local,DC=org'
#$Mailboxes = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -notlike '*$*'} -Properties EmailAddress,msExchRecipientTypeDetails,SamAccountName
#$Mailboxes = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OU -Properties EmailAddress,msExchRecipientTypeDetails,SamAccountName

$Report = @()

foreach ( $Mbx in $Mailboxes ) {
    switch ( $Mbx.msExchRecipientTypeDetails ) {
        1 { 
            $Stats = $Mbx.EmailAddress | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select-Object TotalItemSize,ItemCount
            $Report += [pscustomobject] @{ 
                'Username' = $_.SamAccountName
                'E-Mail' = $Mbx.EmailAddress
                'E-Mail ItemCount' = $Stats.ItemCount
                'TotalItemSize(GB)' = ( [math]::Round( ( $Stats.TotalItemSize -replace "(.*\()|,| [a-z]*\)" )/1GB ),2 )
            }
            break
        }
        default { 
            $Report += [pscustomobject] @{ 
                'Username' = $_.SamAccountName
                'E-Mail' = 'NoEmailAddress'
                'E-Mail ItemCount' = 'NoMailBox'
                'TotalItemSize(GB)' = 'NoMailBox'
            }
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, do not do `-Prop *` unless this is a small to medium sized domain. I just ran a script against a domain that took over a day to finish, I was only looking for any group affected by a computer object, and it ended up eating over 12 gigs of memory. It can add up fast.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician That seems silly that you wouldn't have stopped it somewhere in there. This could easily be fixed by not using * and using -Properties EmailAddress,msExchRecipientTypeDetails,SamAccountName

Comment: I was not using `-Prop *`, I was only getting the default properties and actually only storing the ObjectClass for each object in a group. I was admittedly working with almost 700,000 users and computers, but my point remains that if they are querying the entire active directory they probably don't want to use `-Prop *` on the query.

Answer (score 0):

@Shawn Esterman - thanks for the input -- below code works like a charm. Explicitly stated properties to search on.

```
cls

$Users = @()
$Report = @()
$UserObj = @()
$ADUser = @()
$Mbx = @()
$OU = @()
$Mailboxes = @()

$Users = @("user1",'user2','user3','user4','user5')
$Mailboxes = $Users | Get-ADuser -Properties EmailAddress,msExchRecipientTypeDetails,SamAccountName


$OU = 'DC=local,DC=local,DC=local'
$Mailboxes = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU -Filter {SamAccountName -notlike '*$*'} -ResultSetSize 50 -Properties EmailAddress,msExchRecipientTypeDetails,SamAccountName

foreach ($Mbx in $Mailboxes)
{
$UserObj = New-Object PSObject
$UserObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Username" -Value $Mbx.SamAccountName

If($mbx.msExchRecipientTypeDetails -eq $null)
    {     
    $UserObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "E-Mail" -Value "NoEmailAddress"
    $UserObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "email ItemCount" -Value "NoMailBox"
    $UserObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "TotalItemSize(GB)" -Value "NoMailBox"
    Write-Host $Mbx.SamAccountName "has no mailbox" -ForegroundColor green
    }
Else
  {
    If($mbx.msExchRecipientTypeDetails -eq 1)
      {
        $stats = $Mbx.EmailAddress | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select-Object TotalItemSize,TotalDeletedItemSize,ItemCount,LastLogonTime,LastLoggedOnUserAccount
        $MbxSizeb = $stats.TotalItemSize -replace "(.*\()|,| [a-z]*\)"
        $Tmp_gb = $MbxSizeb/1GB
        $MbxSizeGB = [math]::Round($Tmp_gb,2)

        $UserObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "E-Mail" -Value $Mbx.EmailAddress
        $UserObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "email ItemCount" -Value $stats.ItemCount
        $UserObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "TotalItemSize(GB)" -Value $MbxSizeGB
      }
  }  
$Report = $Report += $UserObj
```

}